# Refreshing SBT project in Intellij Idea switches Java to 7

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

I was having a Play 2.4.2 scala project built with J7 in IntelliJ Idea, then I switched the project to Play 2.5.0 with J8. I have modified J7->J8 everywhere I could think of, but for some reason, when I refresh project in `SBT projects` window in Intellij Idea (and it also refreshes it automatically when I change build.sbt), it sets Java version back to 7 (both options `Project SDK` and `Project language level:` in `Project Structure` window are set back)

I've probably missed some option, but I cannot find anything that still points to J7. Any idea?

I've tried to put this in `build.sbt`, but it did not fix the issue:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-target:jvm-1.8")
```

Sbt compiles project fine if it is compiled SBT terminal, but I prefer to use IntelliJ Idea run option.

Comment: That is indeed weird. Check that not only the `Project SDK` and `Project language level` have the correct Java version but also the individual modules in the project: Project Structure -> Modules -> ..select a module.. -> check tabs `Sources` and `Dependencies`

Comment: @Anton Unfortunately no luck...

Comment: Same issue ... you are not alone.

Answer (score 2):

We're looking into it. Meanwhile, one workaround is editing `.idea/sbt.xml` and change the `jdk` option line to `<option name="jdk" value="1.8" />` (or whatever you named the SDK in your project structure) and then refreshing your project.

**Update:** The [latest Nightlies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly) of the Scala plugin change how the project JDK is set, which should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has a closed ticket for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6823

I have created a new ticket:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10631